# MySQL view - relationship in one row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

table A

```
|| *handtool_id* || *1_wire_type_id* || *2_wire_type_id* || *3_wire_type_id* || *4_wire_type_id* || *5_wire_type_id* || *6_wire_type_id* ||
|| 1 || 5 || 7 || 9 || 1 || 1 || 1 ||
|| 2 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 ||
|| 3 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 ||
|| 4 || 4 || 5 || 7 || 1 || 1 || 1 ||
```

and

table B

```
|| *wire_type_id* || *wire_diameter* || *wire_type* ||
|| 1 || N/A || N/A ||
|| 2 || 0,5 || 5012050ZW ||
|| 3 || 0,75 || 5012075BL ||
|| 4 || 1,0 || 5012100ZW ||
```

i want create one view with results filled values from the table B, but i have wire_type_id repeatedly in one row.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT b.* FROM <tableA> a LEFT JOIN <tableB> b ON b.wire_type_id = a.1_wire_type_id`, still I don't think I understand the question

Comment: .. is okay but i need the value from table b for 2_wire_type_id too.
i need view for example
| *handtool_id* || *1_wire_type_id* || *2_wire_type_id* || *3_wire_type_id* || *4_wire_type_id* || *5_wire_type_id* || *6_wire_type_id* ||
|| 1 || 0,75 || 0,75 || 0,75 || N/A || N/A || N/A ||

Comment: Bad design....can you change the table structure or not ?

Comment: i know, i cant change the structure :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a `LEFT JOIN` on TableB for every iteration of `X_wire_type_id` :

```
SELECT a.handtool_id, 
       b.wire_diameter,
       c.wire_diameter,
       d.wire_diameter,
       e.wire_diameter,
       f.wire_diameter,
       g.wire_diameter
FROM <tableA> a 
LEFT JOIN <tableB> b ON b.wire_type_id = a.1_wire_type_id
LEFT JOIN <tableB> c ON c.wire_type_id = a.2_wire_type_id
LEFT JOIN <tableB> d ON d.wire_type_id = a.3_wire_type_id
LEFT JOIN <tableB> e ON e.wire_type_id = a.4_wire_type_id
LEFT JOIN <tableB> f ON f.wire_type_id = a.5_wire_type_id
LEFT JOIN <tableB> g ON g.wire_type_id = a.6_wire_type_id
```